# Multi Array in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How I create Data Array in C# MVC with format array :

```
MenuHeader
    MenuDetail, Attribute1, Attribute2
MenuHeader2
    MenuDetail, Attribute1, Attribute2
    MenuDetail, Attribute1, Attribute2
    MenuDetail, Attribute1, Attribute2
```

Please Help.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to add some more details or even sample data to make clear what your data structure should look like. From what I see it doesn't actually look like an _array_ would be a good idea here anyway.

Comment: not really sure this could be considered a question about mvc either ... seems more like a question about how classes works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used MenuDetails and such and I have no idea about the right way to do it but what you can do is this:

## Step 1

create a class which takes three properties

```
class MenuDetailsAndAttributes
{
    public MenuDetail menudetail ;
    public Attribute attribute1 ;
    public Attribute attribute2 ;

    public MenuDetailsAndAttributes(/*some parametrs  maybe*/)
    {
        menudetail = new MenuDetail(/*I dont know what to put here, you will need to work them out yourself*/);
        attribute1 = new Attribute();
        attribtue2 = new Attribute();
    }

}
```

## Step 2

And After this make another class

```
class HeaderAndDetails
{
    MenuHeader header;
    public List<MenuDetailsAndAttributes> list;

    public HeaderAndDetails()
    {
        header = new MenuHeader();
        list = new List<MenuDetailsAndAttributes>();
    }
}
```

## Step 4

Now you can write tons of unnecessary code to add/remove/set/change and construct every class inside these lists

## Important Note

I hope you understand what I did there. What I tried to do ther is combine

```
MenuDetail, Attribute1, Attribute2
```

into a class, and combine a list of that class with `MenuHeader` and create a new class, and create list of that class so you can use it as many times you want.

I guess this is very wrong and unnecessarily long but you can pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

Usually menus aren't organized in array because they can be nested in each other so they have an hierarchy, one possible way is to create a class

```
class MenuItem 
{
    public MenuItem[] Childs { get; set; }
    public String Detail { get; set; }
    public String[] Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for respons.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MenuId] => 1
            [MenuName] => Menu Header
            [MenuAttribute] =>
            [MenuChild] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MenuId] => 6
                            [MenuName] => Sub Menu 1
                            [MenuIcon] => 
                            [MenuLink] => 
                            [MenuModule] => "ModulMenu1"
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MenuId] => 7
                            [MenuName] => Sub Menu 2
                            [MenuIcon] => 
                            [MenuLink] => 
                            [MenuModule] => "ModulMenu2"
                        )
                )

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [MenuId] => 2
            [MenuName] => Configuration
            [MenuAttribute] => 
            [MenuChild] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [MenuId] => 14
                            [MenuName] => Sub Menu 2-1
                            [MenuIcon] => 
                            [MenuLink] => 
                            [MenuModule] => "ModulMenu2-1"
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [MenuId] => 15
                            [MenuName] => Sub Menu 2-2
                            [MenuIcon] => 
                            [MenuLink] => 
                            [MenuModule] => "ModulMenu2-2"
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [MenuId] => 16
                            [MenuName] => Sub Menu 2-3
                            [MenuIcon] => 
                            [MenuLink] => 
                            [MenuModule] => "ModulMenu2-3"
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Here is an example of the data I mean..

thank you.

Comment: hello, 
basically, I made a menu list using arrays ..

but if there is another way to define it, I hope to implement it

Comment: Yes Check my answer at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Create a class

```
    public class MenuItems
    {
         public int MenuId { get; set; }
         public string MenuName { get; set; }
         public string MenuAttribute { get; set; }
         public List<MenuItems> MenuChild { get; set; }
    }
```

Then use it like

```
   List<MenuItems> data = new List<MenuItems>();
```

and fill the list in nested loop.